# Multiple ON clauses in the JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Is it possible to have two `ON` statements in `JOIN`?

I have two tables:

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| start_date    | date    |
| end_date      | date    |
| price         | int     |
+---------------+---------+

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| purchase_date | date    |
| units         | int     |
+---------------+---------+
```

When I make a `JOIN` I write: `ON table1.product_id=table2.product_id`. But how can I add the clause that the `purchase_date` is also between `start_date` and `end_date`. I cannot get the right answer when I use a `WHERE` statement.

Comment: look again: table1.product_id=table2.product_id

Comment: I assure you, I know what a query looks like. There's no query here.

Comment: `ON (A = A AND B = B)` .... use `AND` to use ON multiple arguments. *(Brackets are for illustation only and not needed for the SQL)*

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry on this one, you should provide a complete query so we can further see what is going on and what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
  AND t2.purchase_date BETWEEN t1.start_date AND t1.end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple conditions in the ON clause

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
  AND table2.purchase_date >= table1.start_date
  AND table2.purchase_date <= table1.end_date
-- ADD WHERE CLAUSE HERE IF NEEDED
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. what is the difference between `ON` and `WHERE`?

Comment: ON is just for the correlation for the 2 tables that you are attempting to JOIN to.
WHERE is the condition for the result set as a whole

Comment: perfect this answers my question. thanks for your time